# Bean property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication' is not writable or has an invalid setter method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, grails

I am running a grails app version 1.3.7. Grails compile is good but when I do grails run-app, I get the following error. Any help on why this is thrown?

> ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error
>   creating bean with name 'authenticationProcessingFilter': Cannot
>   resolve reference to bean 'authenticationManager' while setting bean
>   property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'authenticationManager': Error setting
>   property values; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication' of bean class
>   [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager]: Bean
>   property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication' is not writable or has
>   an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match
>   the return type of the getter?
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'authenticationProcessingFilter': Cannot
>   resolve reference to bean 'authenticationManager' while setting bean
>   property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'authenticationManager': Error setting
>   property values; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication' of bean class
>   [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager]: Bean
>   property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication' is not writable or has
>   an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match
>   the return type of the getter?    at
>   org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)     at
>   grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)  at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
>     at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)   at
>   _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
>     at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
>     at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)    at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)   at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)   at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)     at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:33)    at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)  at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)  at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)  at
>   gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)     at
>   gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)  at
>   gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)   at
>   gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)   at
>   gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)    at
>   gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)   at
>   gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)     at
>   gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'authenticationManager': Error setting
>   property values; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication' of bean class
>   [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager]: Bean
>   property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication' is not writable or has
>   an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match
>   the return type of the getter?    ... 23 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication' of bean class
>   [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager]: Bean
>   property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication' is not writable or has
>   an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match
>   the return type of the getter?    ... 23 more

Comment: I would recommend looking at your configuration and any custom beans defined in `Resources.groovy` for `eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication` that seems to be the issue. Did you upgrade a plugin or something? More information/background on when or how this started to happen will help.

Comment: I am trying to run an old application under grails sdk version 1.3.7. I put org.springframework.security.core-3.0.0.release.jar in the lib folder of the app. spring security version is mentioned as 3.0.7.RELEASE in pom.xml. I had this application running under this setting but now all of a sudden it is failing.

Comment: There is nothing defined in resources.groovy. I have installed Vaadin and included that in the project settings.